# Populating parent grid from editor combo

Tags: extjs, extjs3

i have a grid in ext 3.4 having one of the columns with a combobox editor.
{header: ' Facility', dataIndex: 'facility',editor: borrfacCombo}

The underlying store of the grid has 2 fields (and more) - facility and facilityid

The editor combo is loaded from a store which has a mapping of id and description(something similar to below):

```
borrfacCombo=Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', 
{     displayField: 'name',
     valueField: 'id',
     store: { 
     fields: ['id', 'name'],
     data: [ 
         {id: 'scheme2', name: 'Green Envy'},
     ...         
     ]     
     } 
     });
```

When a particular 'facility' is selected in the combo - I need the corresponding 'facilityid' to be populated in the selected row of the grid's store.
i am trying the following on 'select' in the combo -

```
listeners:{
select:function(combo, record, index) {
 var val=record.get('id');
 var grid=combo.ownerCt.floatParent;
 var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
.... }
 }
```

But 'combo.ownerCt' always shows up as 'undefined'.
How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Without seeing your complete hierarchy of components, we can only advise you to set an id on the grid and use `Ext.getCmp("yourGridId")`. Otherwise, one of the following could also work: `combo.up('grid')` (if combo is a child of the grid, for instance because it is in the grid's toolbar), `combo.up('panel').down('grid')` (if grid and combo are in the same panel)...

Comment: Ext.getCmp is indeed what i did.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
combo.ownerCt.up();
```